# What are the contributions of Professor Hans List?

Tags: 20th-century, europe, technology, individuals

Considering his academic titles, what are the contribution of the automotive engineer, Professor Dr Dr h.c.mult. Hans List? What did he invent? I could not find anything except a [brief obituary](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/obituaries/obituary-professor-hans-list-1363240.html).

Comment: He warrants an article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_List). The [Deutsch version](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_List) has more details.

Comment: I would not give too much attention to the many titles. (The English Wikipedia article also alludes to this.) For what I know, he founded AVL which is a big employer in the area of Graz (a provincial capital in Austria) and a significant player in the area of combustion engine research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think his honors are described in the bio you cite. He spent 50 years in academia, and as the title states,

> The appellation "Dr Dr h.c.mult." shortens the Latin honoris causa multitudo - roughly "many honorary doctorates" - the first for his original Doctorate of Technical Science at Graz, the second for four other university honours.

If you need details on the specific university honors, I would suggest checking with the University of Graz, where he spent the majority of his academic career.  Alternatively state university of Tongji, Woosung, in China

On the other hand, I'm willing to give him respect for being 100 years old and coming in to work the day before he died.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I very interested in technology and AFV history and know a little about diesel engine with so called Schnürle porting, a compact valveless two-stroke engine with direct injection that was developed by this talented Austrian engineer in about 1942. But the details are unknown to me :(

Comment: Ahem ... what are the contributions of "[Professor Arnold Schwarzenegger](http://www.r20vienna.org/)"? :)